# ANDROID - How to apply a different theme to a product flavour?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-productflavors, android-color

I'm not very familiar with working with product flavours and applying different themes to them.

Basically I'm working on an app that is going to have a reskin to a different set of colours/themes. The codebase should be the same, just the theme/logo is different between them.

What's the best way to go around this?

Is it recommended to just have different source sets for each flavour? Eg. `android/main/src` will contain default color/styles and `android/chocolate/src` will have specific color/styles for the `chocolate` flavour?

Answer (score 0):

It's `src/flavor{main}`, but yes. Ideally, the `styles.xml` file would only be on main, but `color/drawables` and `values/strings.xml` will be different across source sets with the same identifiers.